# Find duplicate integer in an array

Tags: java, arrays

The question I came across in my assignment: There is an array of n integers, all within range from 1 to 1000000, there are at least one pair of equal integers, how can u find the first pair ? The requirement is to accomplish a time complexity of O(n), so nested loop is NOT an option, and the language is java. Any suggestions ?

Comment: show your code what did you

Comment: Why you can't use a Set? When you add the values, if add return false it means it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a `boolean[]` array just to mark if I've already found some number on a previous step of the iteration.

For example:

```
int[] input = { .... };
boolean[] found = new boolean[1000000];
int result = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
   if (!found[input[i]]) {
       found[input[i]] = true;
   } else {
       result = input[i];
       break;
   }
}

System.out.println("I found a pair of " + result);
```

Answer (score -1):

just count the number of occurrence of a number in the array. To accomplish the goal, you can choose to use array, HashMap, HashSet, whatever.

As there requirement is to find the first duplicate, if I have to use set, I would do as follows:

```
int[] numbers = ...
Set<Integer> numberSet = new HashSet<>();

for ( int number : numbers ) {
    if ( ! numberSet.add(number) ) {
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: contains is redundant in this case as add already returns a boolean if the object was already present in the Set ;)